# Strange behaviour of limit in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I tried two queries. First one looks like this (it simply lists all data):

```
# listing 1
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, F
....
.... connection etc
s = Search(using=db,index="reestr")
rows = s.execute()
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

`listing 1` prints out all documents from the database. The strange thing happens, when I try to limit the number of documents like so:

```
# listing 2
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, F
....
.... connection etc
s = Search(using=db,index="reestr").filter(F("limit", value=1))
rows = s.execute()
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

In this case it prints several documents, but not one as expected (I expect it by setting `value=1`). So, what's wrong with that and how one limits the number of documents in `Elasticsearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`limit` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) doesn't limit the number of documents that are returned, just the number of documents that the query executes on each shard.

If you want to limit the number of documents returned, you need to use the `size` parameter or in your case the [Python slicing API](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination) like this:

```
# listing 1
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, F
....
.... connection etc
s = Search(using=db,index="reestr")
s = s[0:1]                <------  limit to only one document
rows = s.execute()
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```